# How to use python pandas groupby or .DataFrameGroupBy objects to create unique list of combinations

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Is there a more efficient way to use pandas groupby or pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object to create a unique list, series or dataframe, where I want unique combinations of 2 of N columns. E.g., if I have columns: Date, Name, Item Purchased and I just want to know unique Name and Date combination this works fine:

```
y = x.groupby(['Date','Name']).count()
y = y.reset_index()[['Date', 'Name']]
```

but I feel like there should be a cleaner way using

```
y = x.groupby(['Date','Name'])
```

but y.index gives me an error, although y.keys works. This actually leads me to ask the general question as what are pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy objects convenient for?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need that `y.keys` doesn't give you?

Comment: "y.index gives me an error," please can you show the error? ideally with an example DataFrame which demonstrates it.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use -- and in fact shouldn't use -- groupby here. You could use [drop_duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to get unique rows instead:

```
x.drop_duplicates(['Date','Name'])
```

Demo:

```
In [156]: x = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[0,1,2]*2, 'Name':list('ABC')*2})

In [158]: x
Out[158]: 
   Date Name
0     0    A
1     1    B
2     2    C
3     0    A
4     1    B
5     2    C

In [160]: x.drop_duplicates(['Date','Name'])
Out[160]: 
   Date Name
0     0    A
1     1    B
2     2    C
```

---

You shouldn't use groupby because

1. `x.groupby(['Date','Name']).count()` performs a count of the
   number of elements in each group, but the count is not used -- it's a wasted computation.
2. `x.groupby(['Date','Name']).count()` raises an AttributeError if
   `x` has only `Date` and `Name` columns.
3. `drop_duplicates` is much much faster for this purpose.

[Use `groupby` when you want to perform some operation on each group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine), such as counting the number of elements in each group, or computing some statistic (e.g. a sum or mean, etc.) per group.